How can I store guitar tabs in MySQL Database?
I want to make a browser application where you can choose between many guitar tabs and display them like this:
e|----5-7----7-|-8-----8-2-----2-|-0---------0-----|-----------------|
B|---5---5-----|---5-------3-----|---1---1-----1---|-0-1-1-----------|
G|---5-----5---|-----5-------2---|-----2---------2-|-----------------|
D|-7-----------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
A|-------------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|
E|-------------|-----------------|-----------------|-----------------|

Letters: name of the string
Digits: guitar fret

I want to make a Database with 5-10 songs saved in .txt files and then in the browser to have the choice to choose from them and when clicked to be displayed the particular tab.
Can you help me? If you have better ideas I will be happy to hear them.
I am currently stuck in this problem

Why do you want to store guitar tabs in a relational database? Do you need to compare them or search within songs? If so, how would you compare or search within them? The way you want to use them (query them) determines how to structure the data.

If you just want to display the whole song as is, then either do not store them in a database, or just use a text column.

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

@Shadow I dont' want to compare them. I just want to display them in browser, but I am not sure how to store them?

If you just want to display them, then store them in files or just in a simple text field in mysql.
